# In Linux fwrite command does not set errno, how to get proper errno on failure cases

Tags: c, linux, fwrite

From man page of fwrite in linux,

**DESCRIPTION**
       The function fread() reads nmemb elements of data, each size bytes long, from the stream pointed to by stream, storing them at the location given by ptr.

```
   The function fwrite() writes nmemb elements of data, each size bytes long, to the stream pointed to by stream, obtaining them from the location given by ptr.

   For nonlocking counterparts, see unlocked_stdio(3).
```

**RETURN VALUE**
       On  success,  fread() and fwrite() return the number of items read or written.  This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1.  If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached,
       the return value is a short item count (or zero).

```
   fread() does not distinguish between end-of-file and error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred.
```

***Now my question is:***
Suppose fwrite() system call failure occurred due to No space on the drive. How can we get the errno for it. As fwrite is not setting the errno in case of failure.

**Just in case errno is:**
The  header file defines the integer variable errno, which
is set by system calls and some library functions in the event of an
error to indicate what went wrong.

**Talking in terms of Programming language:** C

Comment: Are you asking about what you can do practically, or about the C standard?

Comment: The man page you have quoted already tells you: "callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which occurred".

Comment: The man page does not answer the question. feof() shouldn't apply to fwrite(), only to fread(). In the case of fread(), feof() and ferror() can be used to determine whether the failure was because of (a) EOF or (b) any error whatsoever, but ferror() does not indicate which specific error occurred in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite()` is not a direct system call, and in general all I/O done via a `FILE *` pointer is buffered. There is no guarantee that a call to `fwrite()` will actually perform a write at that time. Errors can be returned immediately, or by later calls to functions using `FILE *`. However, `fclose()` will write out any remaining buffered data, and will return an error if that write did not succeed.

In summary, you need to check for errors during every call to `fwrite()`, `fread()` *and* `fclose()`. If you want to avoid doing error checking everywhere, you can call `ferror()` at any time to check the error status of a `FILE *`.

The variable `errno` is set when errors occur, because the C library internally calls `read()` and `write()`, and those set `errno` in case of errors.

Comment: A POSIX extension says fwrite() sets errno

Comment: @MarcH How can one test for the presence of that extension during compilation?

Comment: I'm not sure, `#ifdef _POSIX_VERSION` is probably enough. Search for "fwrite+opengroup"

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite()` cannot fail due to EOF, but fread() can.

For fwrite(), you discover an error if it did not write the same amount of items you told it to, so you check it like this:

```
size_t written = fwrite(buf, element_size, num_elements, file);
if (written != num_elements) {
   //error , here errno do get set and you can inspect it/print it etc.
}
```

Now, a FILE* have an internal buffer, so a `fwrite()` call might not actually write the data to the operating system or file unless that internal buffer gets full.

This means you also either have to `fflush()` the FILE* and also check for errors after each `fwrite()` call like so:

```
if (fflush(file) == EOF) {
       //error , here errno do get set and you can inspect it/print it etc.
}
```

Or you have to accept that a potential write failure can be given to you on any future `fwrite()` calls you perform if e.g. those calls happens to flush() the FILE* automatically.
And you'd also have to check for errors when calling `fclose()`:

```
if (fclose(file) == EOF) {
       //error , here errno do get set and you can inspect it/print it etc.
}
```

For `fread()` you can inspect errno if it failed. After you have handled any data an `fread()` call have read, you can do

```
if (ferror(file)) {
     //error , here errno do get set and you can inspect it/print it etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*As fwrite is not setting the errno in case of failure*: not exactly. The only possible error for fwrite is an error that would occur during the call of the underlying `write` system call. In that case the errno variable will be set but the `write` call and as such will be available, and you will be able to directly use the strerror or perror functions to get a textual description of the error.

BTW, fwrite is **not** a system call but a standard library function: is does not directly call a kernel function.